# why the following react code render three thimes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**why the following react code render three thimes, what is the mechanism of react rendering**

```
import React  from 'react';

const Toggle = (props) => {
  const [ num ,setNumber ] = React.useState(0)
  setTimeout(() => {
        setNumber(1)
  }, 0)
  console.log('render'); // render three times ?
  return <button >{ console.log(num) } {num}</button>
};

export default Toggle;
```

**And the following react code render one thimes**

```
import React  from 'react';

const Toggle = (props) => {
  const [ num ,setNumber ] = React.useState(0)
  setTimeout(() => {
        setNumber(0) // change
  }, 0)
  console.log('render'); // render one times ?
  return <button >{ console.log(num) } {num}</button>
};

export default Toggle;
```

Comment: The second snippet renders only once (initial render) because React is able to detect that `num` did not change and doesn't see a reason to rerender. Why the first snippet rerenders three times instead of two, is a good question

Comment: The 1st snippet outputs render 4 times for me the unexpected behaviour is because the `setTimeout` is called every time a render occurs (verify by `console.log` inside it) if you had used `React.useEffect(() => {}, [])` it would have shown render twice only as you have expected

Answer (score 0):

As you know, Node is asynchronous javascript and also non-blocking.

So it first execute `console.log('render');`, after that whrn the setTimeout time comes it execute line by line from `setTimeout(() => {` inside the setTimeout there is a state change `setNumber(1)` for this the whole program execute again. This is the reason tou see `console.log('render');` executes three times. You can understand better if you increase setTimeout time.

then the reason behind 2nd code `console.log('render');` just one is the react virtual dom.

Comment: why not render twice but three times